# Filtering Using the Results of Grouping

Tags: r, dplyr

Within my full data set, there are repeated surveys in the same areas. My problem is that I'm trying to select those for which they have been surveyed in each year that surveys were performed. One other situation involves those that have been surveyed at least 3 out of the 4 times.

I've produced the following example data set in order to highlight what I'm trying to do:

```
id   area_id   year
 1         1   2010
 2         1   2011
 3         1   2012
 4         1   2013
 5         2   2010
 6         2   2011
 7         2   2013
 8         3   2010
 9         3   2012
10         4   2012
```

With the following code to easily create it:

```
ex_df <- data.frame(id = 1:10,
                    area_id = c(rep(1, 4), rep(2, 3), rep(3, 2), 4),
                    year = c(2010:2013, 2010, 2011, 2013, 2010, 2012, 2012))
```

My simplistic understanding of `dplyr` has me doing

```
ex_df %>% group_by(area_id, year) %>% ???
```

so far but the ??? represents where I'm lost as to how to filter this to return a vector of the IDs relating to my requirements.

For the first problem, I would want to filter to give the vector `(1, 2, 3, 4)` as `area_id 1` was the only one surveyed in all 4 years.

For the second problem, I would want the vector to be `(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7)`.

What would be the appropriate way to manage this?

Comment: Please mention what is the expected output in your post too.

Comment: Already did? In the final part of the post I state the vectors I would want the function to be returning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For case 1:

```
ex_df %>%
    group_by(area_id) %>%
    filter(n() == 4) %>%
    pull(id)
#[1] 1 2 3 4
```

For case 2:

```
ex_df %>%
    group_by(area_id) %>%
    filter(n() >= 3) %>%
    pull(id)
#[1] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
```

Comment: Thanks, my example data set isn't a good representation, but I've just used this successfully :)

Comment: Glad to hear @Syzorr.

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
required_years <- 2010:2013

ex_df2 <- ex_df %>%
  group_by(area_id) %>%
  mutate(
    fouryears = all(required_years %in% year),
    threeyears = sum(required_years %in% year) >= 3
  )
ex_df2
# Source: local data frame [10 x 5]
# Groups: area_id [4]
#       id area_id  year fouryears threeyears
#    <int>   <dbl> <dbl>     <lgl>      <lgl>
# 1      1       1  2010      TRUE       TRUE
# 2      2       1  2011      TRUE       TRUE
# 3      3       1  2012      TRUE       TRUE
# 4      4       1  2013      TRUE       TRUE
# 5      5       2  2010     FALSE       TRUE
# 6      6       2  2011     FALSE       TRUE
# 7      7       2  2013     FALSE       TRUE
# 8      8       3  2010     FALSE      FALSE
# 9      9       3  2012     FALSE      FALSE
# 10    10       4  2012     FALSE      FALSE
```

(where you can `pull` to grab what you need)

```
filter(ex_df2, fouryears) %>% pull(id)
# [1] 1 2 3 4
filter(ex_df2, threeyears) %>% pull(id)
# [1] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
```